# Linux asm - int 16h analogue to read raw keyboard scancodes

Tags: linux, assembly, keyboard, nasm, scancodes

For my studies I need to write a program on asm, which will wait until the keyboard key is pressed, and then print it's scan-code and ASCII code of the key's character.

I know that BIOS's `int 16h` can do the job, but I am using Linux right now and can't find an appropriate analogue syscall for it.

What should I use for this task? I am currently using Debian Stretch and NASM for my assembly code.

Comment: This is not easily possible due to the keyboard being several layers of abstraction away from your program.  For a console application, the easiest way is to first set the terminal into unbuffered mode and then to read a single character.  This is a bit annoying to do but feasible from assembly.

Comment: Another approach, which might lead to simpler code but more complex preparations to execute, would be to write a real-mode program that just uses `int 16h` (and other appropriate BIOS features), compile it to a self-contained binary, and install that where the PC's bootloader (often GRUB) can find and execute it.  For testing, you could run a virtual PC and use the virtual bootloader to run your binary.

Comment: You might be able to use the "input" subsystem for this. See [man input-events](http://manpages.ubuntu.com/manpages/xenial/man8/input-events.8.html).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Normally the kernel translates keyboard scancodes into ASCII characters that you can read on a tty.  But there are ways to get raw scancodes, e.g. look at how [`showkey(1)`](https://jlk.fjfi.cvut.cz/arch/manpages/man/showkey.1) does it (http://kbd-project.org/) on a text console.  https://wiki.archlinux.org/index.php/Keyboard_input

https://github.com/legionus/kbd/blob/2.0.4/src/showkey.c shows that you can **use an `ioctl(2)` on a file descriptor for the console terminal** to set the KBD translation mode to RAW (scancodes) or MEDIUMRAW (keycodes).  Then you can make normal `read` system calls.

```
ioctl(fd, KDSKBMODE, show_keycodes ? K_MEDIUMRAW : K_RAW)
```

Obviously you can make these system calls from hand-written asm using `syscall` on x86-64 or `int 0x80` on 32-bit x86, looking up the syscall numbers in `asm/unistd_64.h`, and the values of other constants in their respective headers.

---

**`showkey` takes care to set up a watchdog timer to exit cleanly, and catch signals, because doing this intercepts keys *before* the kernel processes control-C or ctrl+alt+f2 sequences**.  So without a timeout, there'd be no way to exit the program.  And if you exited without restoring normal mode, there'd be no way to type on the console to run a command to restore normal keyboard mode.

Comment: Note that this only works in the virtual console, not inside a terminal emulator.